# Sql query to select different row with same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table and I wanted to get a row with same ID but different values.

lets assume I don't know the IDs;

[image: lets say I have;]

I have feature "one" and I want to find the feature that has same ID with feature "one".

Comment: That would be 'four' - and e4c5 is quite mistaken. In this instance, the PK would be formed on both columns.

Comment: In my case it can be. Don't think like an primary key ID just say a row named ID @e4c5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   features f_outer
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   features f_inner
               WHERE  f_outer.id = f_inner.id AND
                      f_outer.feature != f_inner.feature AND
                      f_inner.feature = 'one')
```

Comment: @Strawberry The OP seems to only want the information from the "other" feature (`f_outer` in my query). You could join and have only one table in the select list, but that always felt funky to me. Especially if you have more than two features with the same id.

Comment: I can't see how this is less funky. I guess I'm just 'old school'

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with 'funky';

```
SELECT y.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.feature <> x.feature
 WHERE x.feature = 'one';
```

Comment: thanks for quick answers guys. Just have one more question, Can I select Only the feature  that I don't have, I mean, I have "one" and in the result I don't want to see feature "one". Just feature "four"

Answer (score 1):

As Strawberry commented, you could use an inner join:

```
SELECT f2.feature
FROM feature f1
INNER JOIN feature f2 ON f1.id = f2.id AND f1.feature <> f2.feature
WHERE f1.feature='one'
```